# Bragg Diffraction with Lasers?

Tags: diffraction, x-ray-crystallography

I've run a lot of laser diffraction experiments with nothing more than a quality laser pen, some rasor blades, a human hair and a small hole in a Christmas card as demonstrations for laymen but I'm kind of bored with these now.

I'd really like to emulate X-ray crystallography diffraction, in a backyard lab setting but found it hard to get (Google) some information on that.

One possibility is to construct a macroscopic $\text{NaCl}$-style lattice from copper single filaments, with a $d$ of about $0.1\,\mathrm{mm}$. That would of course not be easy to pull off but not impossible either, IMO.

I do have another idea, which I want to keep 'under wraps' for now because I'll be test driving it shortly.

Searching P.SE for 'laser diffraction' I came across one intriguing comment claiming  $\text{XRD}$-style laser diffraction may be possible with *synthetic Opal*. Googling then threw up large amounts of links to applications of laser diffraction in the field of particle characterisations (something I'm not interested in for now).

And then there's a paper titled *Linear and Nonlinear Optics of Synthetic Opal* by *M. V. Vasnetsov, V. Yu. Bazhenov, V. V. Ponevchinsky*, which throws a little light on the structure of (a) synthetic Opal: [image: the structure of one synthetic Opal]

But with a lattice $d \approx 100\,\mathrm{nm}$ it isn't clear how such a material could exhibit *'laser $\text{XRD}$'*.

Commercial synthetic Opals are not expensive and readily available but the samples I've seen are all either non-transparent or transparent like glass, so it's hard to see how they could produce the effect I'm looking for.

A beautiful (commercial) sample of synthetic Opal (about $8\,\mathrm{g}$):

[image: Opal]

The fascinating coulours of Opals are attributed to diffraction.

Does anyone here have experience/information on laser $\text{XRD}$ with Opal or anyother substrates?

Comment: You should take a look at a book called "Atlas of Optical Transforms" by Harburn, Taylor and Welberry.

Comment: Perhaps use a printer to print small black dots on a transparency and stack layers of small pieces of that to mimic a crystal structure, e.g., NaCl. Just a thought.

Comment: @EdV Yup: like that idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot give you information about Opals but only last week I came across a rainbow coloured *Happy Birthday* banner as shown below.

[image]

I flattened one corner with a couple of microscope slides and a paper clamp.

[image]

Using a couple of holders (as I do not a third hand to take the photograph I was able to get a 2-D diffractions pattern from which I was able to evaluate the "crossed" grating line spacing.

[image]

Comment: Hey, that's wonderful! So you shone the laser (a pointer pen?) straight (perpendicularly) on the material? What gave you the idea?

Comment: I wondered about the colouration of the banner which was characteristic of a diffraction/interference pattern.  Shifting colours as the banner or my eyes moved.

Comment: Yes, of course. For that reason Opal should also be useable for 'laser $\text{XRF}$' because its fleeting colours are due also to diffraction. Time to buy!

Comment: I've also bought a similar Happy Birthday banner with those interesting 'ecanescent' colours, so time to experiment.

Comment: What laser did you use? With my $532\,\mathrm{nm}$ green laser I'm getting very variable results but nothing as definite as your result. Interestingly my red $650\,\mathrm{nm}$ laser shows $zero$ diffraction, indicating the "$d$" must be smaller than that value.

Comment: About seven years ago from Amazon (UK) *Green/Red/Blue Beam Laser Pointer Combo 3 Laser Light Pens 1mw 532nm 650nm 405nm Triple Colors Astronomy Powerful*.  I would suggest it is the banner which might be at fault? I have just checked and the diffraction pattern can be formed from all parts of the banner although better when the light passes through the silver bit.

Comment: Try making a double slit as I explained here, [How can a double slit interference pattern be created without out going through a double slit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/479082/how-can-a-double-slit-interference-pattern-be-created-without-out-going-through/479114#479114) to check the laser. PS I am just going to borrow my wife's opal!

Comment: That's very interesting too. The banner show very vivid diffraction. The material is highly anisotropic though. I'll try that thing about the silver spots. The laser should be fine: I've run countless double slits before. Ta.

Comment: My result is great with a blue $432\,\\mathrm{nm}$ laser (unfortunately the photos are too heavy (>2 meg) to upload. It also seems my plastic generates much more scatter, at least with the green laser...

Comment: @Gert Were you able to get an estimate of the spacing?

Comment: No, I need to look up how to do that again. Also, need to check for 2nd order. I would urge you to try with your $432\,\mathrm{nm}$ laser. Also, it's clear your banner and mine aren't the same: with the green laser I get enormous amounts of scatter.