# DIY Experiment fiasco: Single slit laser pointer already showing interference pattern

Tags: optics, laser, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

I tried to run the double slit experiment at home for my kid with a cheap red laser pointer. I partially covered the laser with four pieces of electrical tape to make a tiny square hole. To my surprise that was enough to get a cross shaped interference pattern on my wall with a splatter of other dots around it.

[image: covered laser hole]
[image: setup]
[image: cross interference]
[image: cross interference zoom]

When I covered the hole with a single hair strand I did get the nice classic new line of interference (perpendicular to the hair).

The "why do I get the cross beforehand" seems to be answered here ([How can a single slit diffraction produce an interference pattern?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61455/how-can-a-single-slit-diffraction-produce-an-interference-pattern)) that unfortunately I only partially understand. Is there an easy way to fix this? Is my laser not producing "coherent enough" light and I need a different light source? Is the hole still too big (too small)? Would it help if I managed to place the slit further away?

Thanks!

[image: interference with hair]
[image: interference with hair marked]

Comment: In my answer to the question I explain how to make a double slit.  [How can a double slit interference pattern be created without out going through a double slit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/479082/how-can-a-double-slit-interference-pattern-be-created-without-out-going-through/479114#479114).

Comment: I’m unclear on what the problem is here. You want to demonstrate diffraction, but you’d rather it be double-slit diffraction because you understand it better than single-slit diffraction?

Comment: How was the hair orientated relative to the square hole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure that your laser pointer is fine for the job.

The cross is due to the fact that your hole is square.
Try making a six sided hole and see what you get - 3 lines inclined at $60^\circ$ to one another?

It is due to the diffraction of light and called a [diffraction spike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction_spike) or starburst effect in photograph as shown below.

[image]

If you do not want the starburst then use a circular hole.